# Can't update Nexus 5 driver on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7-x64, usb-drive, nexus-5

I'm trying to connect my Nexus 5 to my Windows 7 (64 bits even though I don't think it makes any difference) in order to deploy and test some apps.

I updated the USB driver from "SDK Manager -> Extras".
I downloaded the latest usb driver from android development web page.

The solution I found seaarching on google and on stack overflow was:
 - Go to Windows device manager

- Select Nexus 5 under "Other devices"

  (- Uninstall driver) - I tried inserting this step after the next ones failed
- Update driver
- Browse from computer
- Select the downloaded usb driver (tried selecting the one downloaded from the web page and the one from sdk manager)

Windows still tells me it can't find the driver.

Yes, I checked the "include sub-folders" option.

Yes, the USB debugging mode is on.

Yes, I've tried this with MTP and PTP enabled and disabled (the four possible combinations).

Nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try installing this driver with `pnputil -i -a winusb.inf` from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1514942

Comment: I dont know But Installing from This My phone get Connected http://www.mediafire.com/download/sj643c2alktcfj3/All+MTK+USB+Driver+2014.rar

Comment: from this rar install "All USB driver" setup Name will be identical to mine

Comment: Tried it. Windows still says it isn't able to locate the driver for the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is wondering I wasn't able to solve this and used another device.

Some time ago (after the release of Android 5) I followed the tutorial again and it worked just fined.